# How to get aggregate days from PHP's DateTime::diff?

Tags: php, datetime

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');
$next_year = new DateTime('+1 year');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($now->diff($tomorrow));
print_r($now->diff($next_year));
echo "</pre>";

DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 10
    [i] => 17
    [s] => 14
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 6015
)

DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 1
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 6015
)
```

any ideas why 'days' shows 6015? why won't it show the total number of days? 1 year difference means nothing to me, since months have varying number of days.

Comment: This _never_ worked for me neither.

Comment: This bug is now fixed in the latest versions of PHP.

Answer (score 6):

A more appropriate bug report to follow would be [#51184](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184) which focuses on the problem of Windows reporting 6015 days (non-Windows appears OK).

No feedback has been given as yet with regards to whether the fix for #49778 (which deals with a different issue) affects this or if the problem persists. If anyone here could take a look and provide some feedback, that would be very kind of you.

Comment: I'm rather confused why they declared they "Won't Fix" this obvious bug...  Just ran into it myself.

Comment: I've added a pretty good substitute function at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184 that uses the native function if it works, else uses an alternate method.

Comment: @fbas the bug tracking system is not the place to post work-around scripts, and here isn't the place to advertise them either.

Answer (score 2):

Please upgrade to the latest php. This error only occurs on php 5.3 VC6.

Comment: Late answer review: This question was asked two years ago, so thanks for adding your confirmation that the problem has since been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
```

should be

```
$now = new DateTime(''2010-01-01 00:00:00'');
```

more in the manual
https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: I don't think so. Per: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

DateTime::__construct  ([  string $time = "now"  [,  DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL  ]] )

 time

    String in a format accepted by strtotime().

Comment: i found a nice link about it
http://ditio.net/2008/06/03/php-datetime-and-datetimezone-tutorial/

he does this in a sample $dateTime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));

hope it helps

Comment: i tested it myslef and have the same result as you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49778 is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

its a bug
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49778

> Thank you for your bug report.
>
> Days is indeed not set when creating a DateInterval using the
>   constructor. A complication with this is that it is impossible to
>   determine the number of days when months or years are specified, since
>   these vary in length. It is possible to fill in the days field in some
>   cases and leave it 0 in others. In any case, it should be documented
>   that the days field is not always available.