# Not expected result for DateInterval::format function

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get aggregate days from PHP's DateTime::diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519261/how-to-get-aggregate-days-from-phps-datetimediff)

I have something like this:

```
$daysDiff = intval($currentDate->diff($dueDate)->format('%R%a'));
```

in the php documentation for DateInterval::format says:

```
%R -- "+" for positive interval, "-" for negative

%a -- the total count of days i the interval
```

I having troubles with the result, always return 6015 as days, with the correct sign, + or -.
I try with different dates for `$currentdate` and `$dueDate`.
Can any body tell me why this behavior.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the values of `$currentDate` and `$dueDate` that you're using?

Comment: $currentDate = new \DateTime()

$dueDate is a value that a get from DB, is a valid DateTime object and always, even with different values a get those 6015 days of difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using it wrong.

[From the manual page on DateTime::diff](http://www.bbc.co.uk)

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Try:

```
$interval = $currentDate->diff($dueDate);
echo $interval->format('%R%a');
```

Editted to add....

Huh. I've just run your code, and it works. The problem must be with how you're generating the DateTimes:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');

$daysDiff = intval($datetime1->diff($datetime2)->format('%R%a'));
echo $daysDiff
```

That outputs '2'

Comment: please check the returned value here:

$datetime1->diff($datetime2)

is an object with some properties like:

y for year
m for moth
...
days for total days, even in this object the value for days is always 6015

Comment: @Oriam - I don't know what you mean, sorry

Comment: @Oriam - see my edit. There's something wrong with the dates that you're generating, I think.

Comment: Nothing my friend, is a fact that this function is not working properly, at least with this parameter '%a', i will try to turn arround with the year count, month count etc, and then make a sum to get the total days :(

Comment: @Oriam - it works just fine for me. Have you tried cutting and pasting the code I added in the last edit?

Comment: @Oriam see my response made in the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519261/how-to-get-aggregate-days-from-phps-datetimediff) linked above.

Comment: Do you try this you are suggesting me?:

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');

$interval = $currentDate->diff($dueDate);
echo $interval->format('%R%a');

the result is:
"+6015" with any dates as datetime1 and datetime2 :(