# Getting days from DateTime() above 30/31 so it doesn't carry over to months

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm calculating the difference between 2 dates using DateTime() and it's working fine. The problem is that I want to have the days format be able to go above a full month so 30/31 or higher.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime($contest->expires_at);

$interval = $future_date->diff($now);
$enddate = $interval->format("%m month, %d days, %h hours, %i minutes");
```

The current problem with this is that when I don't display the months, the days can only go up to 30/31 and anything over that will be carried over to make a new month resetting the days count with the leftover days.
I want to be able to display 42 days when the difference is 6 weeks with this kind of format:

```
$enddate = $interval->format("%d days, %h hours, %i minutes");
```

Is there a quick fix for this or do I need to manually convert the timestamp to seconds and use my own function with modulus operators for this?

Comment: This help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: Use `%a` instead of `%d` (as described in the docs for format) - http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update my php version since this is a bug in my old  and it works perfectly now.

[How to get aggregate days from PHP's DateTime::diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519261/how-to-get-aggregate-days-from-phps-datetimediff)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$enddate = $interval->format("%a days, %h hours, %i minutes");
```

See the [DateInterval::format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) in the manual.

**NOTE**

Take care of the [**bug**](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184) if you're working on windows.

Comment: `$enddate = $interval->format("%m months, %d days, %h hours, %i minutes");` 


This gives me a difference of 0 months, 6 days, 23 hours, 52 minutes. Wich is correct since I'm counting down from a week. When I try:

`$enddate = $interval->format("%a days, %h hours, %i minutes");`

I'm getting 6015 days, 23 hours, 50 minutes?

Comment: @user2294225 that's strange.I've test your code with "2013-06-01 00:00:00" as your `$contest->expires_at` and it shows me the correct response `36 days, 6 hours, 14 minutes`.What's your php version?

Comment: @user2294225, it seems you have already found the bug on windows.:)

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your porblem:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime();

// a period of 2 months
$addPeriod = new DateInterval('P2M');

// adding the period
$future_date->add($addPeriod);

// get the differnce
$interval = $future_date->diff($now);

echo($interval->days) . ' days';
```

For today: `echo` returns '61 days'

// EDIT

To avoid running into the dataInterval-Bug you can use:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime();

// a period of 2 months
$addPeriod = new DateInterval('P2M');

// adding the period
$future_date->add($addPeriod);

// get the difference in second
$diffTimestamp = $future_date->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp();

// convert to days
// 1 day = 86.400 seconds
$diffDays = $diffTimestamp/86400;

echo(floor($diffDays)) . ' days';
```

Comment: I'm only getting 6015 for days. After looking it up I've found its a bug in this php version? [link to the stackoverflow post discussing the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519261/how-to-get-aggregate-days-from-phps-datetimediff)